# How do I pass a parameter from my website (in Javascript) to my amazon bot when implemented using cloud formation?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-lex

My Amazon Lex is hosted on a website. Users are logged into the website and I have to pass their user token from the website to Lex or lambda. The bot is embedded in the website using CloudFormation code snippet. Where and how do I set the parameters to pass into Lex from the website and how do I receive them in Lambda?

Answer (score 2):

How to pass a session attribute when configured with https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/deploy-a-web-ui-for-your-chatbot/
1. In the S3 bucket, modify the JSON config file. You can do this by downloading and then editing locally. Re-upload and load the latest version. 
1.1. Modifications should look like this

```
"lex": {
    "botName": "Chatbot",
    "botAlias": "$LATEST",
    "sessionAttributes": {
      "anything": "testtoken"
    },
    "initialText": "blah blah blah",
    "initialSpeechInstruction": "Say 'Buy Flowers' to get started.",
    "reInitSessionAttributesOnRestart": false
  },
```

1.2. Make sure there is public access to read JSON 
2. follow this: https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-lex-web-ui/issues/63 
Note - parameters are stored as session attributes in Lex. They can easily be stored in dynamo through Lex/Lambda or invoking a lambda in the browser.